# Why do I run out of memory when streaming video from a webcam to YouTube on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, streaming, webcam, libav

I am trying to stream video for a YouTube livestream, which I want to stream 24/7 if possible. I have a Raspberry Pi Model 3 Model B with a USB Webcam (Logitech G922).

I'm using this command for streaming:

```
avconv -ar 44100 -ac 2 -f s16le -i /dev/zero -f video4linux2 -video_size qvga -r 10 -i /dev/video0 -strict experimental -b 350k -f h264 -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/<my_secret_key>
```

When I start streaming `avconv`'s memory use slowly grows to 100% and the process is killed. The only band aid solution I have is to increase the size of the dphys swap file. The bigger the `CONF_SWAPSIZE`, the longer I can stream before it runs out of memory.

Why am I running out of memory?

What can I do about it?

Comment: `avconv` is not `ffmpeg`, maybe try the latter instead and see if that works better?

Comment: Yes, I can try that (but I really want to avoid having to compile ffmpeg on my PI). I'm looking more for technical answers to my questions. I don't know much about streaming. Could the PI be holding images that have already been streamed in memory?

Comment: The answer to “why do I run out of memory” is most likely that the particular version of avconv you're using has a memory leak, not sure if any other explanation is more plausible.